# PostScript Install not sending e-mails after failed callout

Tags: apex, email, callout, postinstall

I have created a post-install script that sends a request to a web server. If the server response's status code is not `204`, the script should send an e-mail alerting me about that.
The problem is that this e-mail is not being sent, even though the request responds with 504.

Am I missing a configuration?

This is the code for the callout

```java
    @future(Callout = true)
    private static void sendVersion(String param1, String param2) {
        Map<String, Object> requestParams = new Map<String, Object>{
            'param1' => param1,
            'param2' => param2
        };
                    
        HttpRequest request = buildRequestObject();
        request.setBody(JSON.serialize(requestParams));
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        Integer responseStatusCode = response.getStatusCode();

        if (responseStatusCode != 204) {
            notifyError('Installation Failure' +
                        '\nparam1: ' + param1 +
                        '\nparam2: ' + param1 +
                        '\nStatus: ' + responseStatusCode +
                        '\nResponse body: ' + response.getBody());
        }
    }


    
    private static void notifyError(String emailBody) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'email@email-provider.com'};
            
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Email Agent');
        mail.setSubject('Salesforce Package - Package Installation Failure');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(emailBody);
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] emailResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }

    private static HttpRequest buildRequestObject() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://domain.com/path/to/endpoint');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        return request;
    }
```

Comment: Check [Email Logs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5) and [Email Deliverability](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_email_deliverability.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you, @identigral. Apparently, it's Google that is blocking the message from being received.